# page--front.html.twig print views block

Tags: twig, view, block

I am converting a HTML theme to Drupal 8 theme.
 I have a region named `hero`. I want to print my views result in the `hero` region.
I can print `{{page.hero}}` in `page--front.page.html` file with custom block but cannot print on the same region with views block.

---

<kbd>page--front.html.twig</kbd>

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>{{page.primary_links}}</div>
    <div>{{page.hero}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

<kbd>minnak.info.yml</kbd>

```
core: 8.x
type: theme
base theme: bootstrap

name: 'minnak Sub-Theme (CDN)'
description: 'Uses the jsDelivr CDN for all CSS and JavaScript. No source     files or compiling is necessary and is recommended for simple sites or beginners.'
package: 'Bootstrap'

regions:
primary_menu: 'Primary Menu'
secondary_menu: 'Secondary Menu'
hero: 'Hero'
navigation: 'Navigation'
navigation_collapsible: 'Navigation (Collapsible)'
header: 'Top Bar'
highlighted: 'Highlighted'
help: 'Help'
content: 'Content'
sidebar_first: 'Primary'
sidebar_second: 'Secondary'
footer: 'Footer'
page_top: 'Page top'
page_bottom: 'Page bottom'

libraries:
  - 'minnak/global-styling'
```

Comment: Please post relevant code

Comment: {{ page.hero }}

Comment: Your yaml should be indented more, also the variable `page` doesn't exists. It would be [regions.hero](http://twigfiddle.com/2c4cy2) if you want to print the variable `hero`

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally filter node type to hero so that it was not shown on the page--html.twig. It was due to my stupidity